# How do I set the style of the current paragraph in a UITextView?

Tags: ios

I am writing an iPhone/iPad application that requires simple word processing capabilities. I'd like to give users the option to add styles to the current paragraph. For example:

1. Type several paragraphs into the `UITextView`
2. Put the cursor in the middle of the second paragraph
3. Press a button that says "center" or "ordered list" or something
4. The entire paragraph takes on that style

After reading through the **documentation** I can't figure out a way to do this without starting at the cursor, reading backwards to a line break, then reading forwards to the next line break, and recording that as the range. Then style the `attributedText` property. Is that the only way to do this?

Comment: Yes, what you’re describing is essentially the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I was hoping there would be an API for identifying current paragraph given you can style them, but I'll use this method.